# Spring security context manipulation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following use case which I'd like to validate:

I have a Resource server lets call it **( service1 )** and another service which will try to get some data from this server **(service 2)**, the call between services is secured with **( OAuth2 )**, so **( service2 )** will send a request to **( service 1 )** with some Access token in the header **( Authorization )** and the resource server will validate this token against some Auth server.

For some use case reasons I can't but customer data inside this token so I'll make another **JWT** token, put customer data inside and send it also along the request with another header **(e.x: Customer-Authorization )**.
On the resource server I'll go with the following approach:

1. Use spring security configurations to validate the first token **(
   sent in Authorization header )**
2. If the previous pass, I'll add a jersey filter which will replace.
   **( Spring security context )** with a new custom one that will handle my second token **sent in Customer-Authorization header**
3. I'll depend on the new Spring security context for getting customer.
   data and make all required authentications **( e.x: using
   @PreAutorize )**

What I'd like to know does this approach has any drawbacks in your opinion? And would you suggest any better approaches?

**( Note 1:** I know its not standard thing to have 2 access tokens, but our current use case require this and we can't change it in the near future )

**( Note 2**: to be little more clear my first token is used for service to service authentication and its **JWT** token I get and authenticate through STUPS **https://github.com/zalando-stups**.

The second token is just a **JWT** token that I generate to store some customer data and scopes inside and use it later in further processing)